# Passing data between classes in the same file

Tags: android, listview

I have a costume `ListView` contents titles and description and I wanna get the clicked row's title and show it in a **Toast**.

My Adapter code:

```
class SingleRow
{
String title;
String description;

SingleRow(String title, String description)
    {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    }
}
class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {


ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
Context context;

Adapter(Context c)
{
    context = c;
    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.lwastitles);
    String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.laws);

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i],descriptions[i]));
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow,viewGroup,false);
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView211);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView112);
    title.setText(list.get(i).title);
    description.setText(list.get(i).description);
    return row;
}
```

}

So I wanna get the `list.get(i).title` to my **MainActivity** to use it in `onItemLongClick`

----------------------MainActivity--------------------------

```
public class Examples extends Activity {

ListView list;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.examplesandlaws);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Where's the code for `MainActivity` that is problematic? Where's your item click listener?

Comment: @TedHopp I posted the main activity, I wanna show the selected title in a Toast?

Comment: Just use your second parameter and get title from row: `TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        SingleRow row = (SingleRow) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), row.title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you problem solved I used this code TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView); by @Geralt